# How can I send data that has already been sent?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am hoping someone may be able to assist as I am lost. I send a file to a customer several times a day that contains multiple Purchase Order numbers and each file contains a different PO# each time. I have a table called EDICUSTOUTBOUND_810_SENT that is updated with the PO# every time an order is sent to ensure I don't send duplicates. Once in a while, a PO# will get split between files and this causes an issue for the customer. What I am trying to do when this happens is include all the items for the PO# from the previous file plus the new items on the second. I cannot figure out how to do this since I update the sent table. What I have now ignores the sent table and just sends everything each run. [EDICUSTOUTBOUND_810_SENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpQX9.png)

```
SELECT 'TAG' as RECORD_TAG,
   'ASN' as DOC_TYPE,
   'CDS' as TPID,
   'RMA' as PARENT_CHAIN,
   To_char(ORD.sched_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')              SCHEDULE_DATE, 
   CST.ship_city                                      FACILITY_CITY,
   CST.ship_state                                     FACILITY_STATE,
   ORD.po_number || '-' || ORD.CUST_NBR               ASN_ID, 
   SD.route_seq || To_char(SD.load_date, 'DDMMYY')    MANIFEST, 
   SD.order_number                                    ORDER_NUMBER,
   SD.ROUTE_SEQ                                       ROUTE_SEQ, 
   SD.LOAD_DATE                                       LOADDATE,
   ORD.CUST_NBR                                       CUST_NBR, 
   ORD.po_number                                      PO_NUM, 
   REPLACE(ORD.contractor, ',', ' ')                  JOB_NAME,
   SD.line_item                                       LINE_ITEM, 
   SD.sub_item                                        SUB_ITEM, 
   CASE WHEN DET.item_qty  > 1 THEN '1' ELSE CAST (DET.item_qty AS VARCHAR2(20))
   END QTY,
   SD.barcode                                         BARCODE,
   DET.prod_line                                      LN, 
   DET.prod_style                                     ST, 
   SD.unit_type                                       WINDOW_PART, 
   REPLACE(SD.okopt_desc, ',', ' ')                   DESCRIPTION
```

FROM   (

```
        SELECT DISTINCT manifest

        FROM (SELECT manifest, order_number
              FROM wsoe.shippingdata
              WHERE load_date >= trunc(sysdate) AND CURPROCESSID = 210  ) sd1   

        JOIN wsoe.ordhead oh1 ON sd1.order_number = oh1.order_number
        LEFT JOIN WSOE.EDICUSTOUTBOUND_810_SENT edi ON oh1.po_number || '-' || oh1.CUST_NBR  = edi.invoice_no
        WHERE edi.invoice_no IS NULL      
   ) m 
   JOIN wsoe.shippingdata sd ON sd.manifest = m.manifest
   JOIN wsoe.ordhead ORD 
     ON SD.order_number = ORD.order_number 
   JOIN wsoe.orddet DET 
     ON DET.order_number = SD.order_number 
        AND DET.line_item = SD.line_item 
        AND DET.sub_item = SD.sub_item 
   JOIN wsoe.customer CST 
     ON CST.cust_nbr = ORD.cust_nbr 
   WHERE Substr(CST.custflags, 60, 1) = 'Y'
       ORDER BY po_num, line_item;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your real problem is that sometimes a PO# gets split between files. The best solution would be to make sure this doesn't happen in the first place. Are you limited by file size or something? Your other code that actually dumps the records to a file to send could be changed to measure the size of the next record and figure out whether it will fit in the current file.

Short of something like that, if you know which PO# you need to resend, you should be able to change your inner query to get a specific PO#. Something like

```
...
JOIN wsoe.ordhead oh1 ON sd1.order_number = oh1.order_number
    LEFT JOIN WSOE.EDICUSTOUTBOUND_810_SENT edi ON oh1.po_number || '-' || oh1.CUST_NBR = edi.invoice_no
    WHERE edi.invoice_no IS NULL OR oh1.po_number = 80
...
```

to include PO number 80 in the next run.

Comment: Yes, ideally I don't want it to split and it shouldn't. The file is a Advanced Ship Notice. These are items scanned and loaded onto a truck. What happens is that an order will get scanned and loaded but one item may get left off for whatever reason. It then gets scanned  and loaded on the same truck later in the day. Unfortunately, I won't know what PO# got split. I'm not limited by file size. It's not always the very next file that it's split between.

Comment: It sounds like the data in `shippingdata` is coming in live, so more `line_item`s may be added after the query runs, yes? So to prevent splits you'd need to exclude trucks that haven't left yet. Does any of your data let you do that? ...To generalize the solution so you re-run a PO IFF more items are added, either store a sum of items/subitems counts between query runs somewhere (probably in `EDICUSTOUTBOUND_810_SENT`), and then compare, OR store the datetime the last query executed, and include POs with new items since that date. first one is better. Are you able to add a column to the table?